# VB.Net - memory usage

Tags: vb.net, winforms, memory

Is there a way to prevent vb.net from loading all the project forms at startup?

I would like to make it so that they are only loaded when they are used... so with the `Load` event on loading into memory and the `Dispose` event on deletion. Since the project has many forms I would like to avoid consuming memory unnecessarily.

Comment: Only the starting Form is created when the application starts. Your assembly is loaded, along with the satellite assemblies it requires (when referenced). Your code creates other windows -- You should probably describe a bit more in depth what the problem is. Maybe you have added a lot of *heavy* objects in the Project's Resources? Or the memory usage simply increases over time? Did you profile the application?